# Excel to Txt with space delimiter

Tags: excel, vba

Below Quote was working fine with appropriate spacing. It no longer works now.

```
Sub FCR()
Dim MyFullName As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim bkp

bkp = Sheet7.Range("O1")

Sheets("FC").Copy
MyFullName = "C:\Users\" & Environ$("username") & "\Desktop\Rates\" + bkp + VBA.Strings.Format(Now, "ddmmyy") + "FC.txt"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.SaveAs Filename:=MyFullName, FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True

    
End Sub
```

Output Now (Not Correct)

```
25-05 001 CMUAU30.200030.120030.02000 30.785030.785031.3700
```

Output Before (Correct)

```
25-05-2022 001 C MUR AUD 30.20000 30.12000 30.02000 30.78500 30.78500 31.37000
```

Comment: OK, so what does it do now? Does it give you an error? What line does it stop on?

Comment: Output Now(Not Correct)
25-05 001
CMUAU30.200030.120030.02000      30.785030.785031.3700

Output Before (Correct)
25-05-2022 001
C MUR AUD 30.20000 30.12000 30.02000          30.78500 30.78500 31.37000

Comment: You may want to explain what you mean by "output"

Comment: It looks like you have different problems: dates have a different format `25-05-2022` instead of `25-05`, spaces are removed (most probably due to `xlTextPrinter` related format) and some things are flat wrong `C MUR AUD` becomes `C MU AU` (but without the spaces), there might be different issues, not only with your macro, but also with the file in general. Are there any other macros involved here?

Comment: @Dominique . No am using only the above macros. Spaces are being removed which is causing this issue. I am not able to solve it.

Comment: @braX. Output is the results generated by the macros.

Comment: Your code does not generate results. It just sets a value and saves the file.

Comment: @Brax . Apologies.  You are right. It saves values from excel  sheet to text format

Comment: If you want a specific format as the output then you should probably write out the file via VBA, rather than relying on saving using `FileFormat:=xlTextPrinter`, which seems to be affected by things like column width and choice of font (?) https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/xltextprinter-and-accounting-format.3454117/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to use spaces as delimiters, but I can use tabs instead.
For that, replace `xlTextPrinter` by `xlText`.

More information can be found on [this page, explaining text formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat), but be careful: `xlText` is not mentioned here.